# Moving towards WayPoints [C#]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, move

I've got this problem: I need that enemies move towards a target position, but my problem is that i wrote this inside the Update function, so the "foreach" statement is done in just one frame. Also, the "waypoint is reached" sentence is never shown. How can I solve this?

Here is the code: `public class WayPointMovement : MonoBehaviour {

```
public EnemyDataSpawn enemy;
private Vector3 lastPos; 

void Start ()
{
    lastPos = gameObject.transform.position; 
}

void Update ()
{
    gameObject.transform.LookAt (LevelManager.current.playerObject.transform);
    //WaypointData is a scriptable object that contains the definition of "x" and "z" coordinates.
    foreach (WaypointData waypoints in enemy.enemy.waypoint) {
        Debug.Log (waypoints.x);
        gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (gameObject.transform.position, new Vector3 (lastPos.x + waypoints.x, 0f, lastPos.z + waypoints.z), Time.deltaTime * enemy.enemy.easySpeedMovement);
        if (gameObject.transform.position.x == lastPos.x + waypoints.x && gameObject.transform.position.z == lastPos.z + waypoints.z) {
            Debug.Log("waypoint reached");
            lastPos = gameObject.transform.position;
        }
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: if `x` and `z` are of floating-point types (eg `double`), it's probably a mistake to compare them for exact equality.

Comment: You can't iterate the full waypoint list in one update, you must store the target waypoint globally and on each update move it according to speed, check if it has reached the waypoint and if it did then change the target waypoint with the next one.

Comment: @Gusman how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rework `Update` so that it only does one frame's worth of work. That means that you have to remember a) which waypoint you're going toward, and b) how far you were through going to it. You only move on to the next waypoint when you actually get to it.

<del>There are two ways to track the progress through waypoints:</del>

<del>1. You can simply delete waypoints once they are reached. Then, the waypoint you're trying to get to is always the first one in the list.</del>

<del>2. If you want to keep the waypoints, then you need an extra variable to track *which* waypoint you're *currently* moving toward. This could be something like an index into an array or list, or it could be an enumerator (`IEnumerator<WaypointData>`) on which you call `MoveNext` each time you finish a waypoint.</del>

You've indicated (in comments on this answer) that you don't want to delete waypoints as you reach them. The most flexible arrangement, allowing you to add new waypoints as you go, is to use an index variable:

```
int waypointIndex;

void Start()
{
  waypointIndex = 0;
}

void Update()
{
  if (waypointIndex < waypoints.Count)
  {
    update position;

    if (reached waypoint)
    {
      waypointIndex++;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your `Update` method, instead of writing a loop, you update your game object's position exactly once, check if it has reached the waypoint just once, and if it has, move on to the next waypoint before returning. If multiple moves are needed to get to a waypoint, you allow those to be multiple calls to `Update`; each `Update` is only one step of the movement.

You will need better logic for determining when you have reached a waypoint. As other commenters have indicated, with floating-point values, simply checking if they are *exactly equal* is not likely to work. Instead, you can check whether the distance to the waypoint is less than `Time.deltaTime * enemy.enemy.easySpeedMovement`, and if it is, then instead of using `Vector3.MoveTowards`, just set the position to the waypoint exactly, and treat that step as having reached the waypoint.

Here's the rough logic (in pseudocode) (but not as pseudocode as when I first wrote it):

```
Vector3 lastPos;
int waypointIndex;

void Start()
{
  lastPos = gameObject.transform.position;
  waypointIndex = 0;
}

void Update()
{
  if (waypointIndex < waypoints.Count)
  {
    waypointPosition = new Vector3 (lastPos.x + waypoints.x, 0f, lastPos.z + waypoints.z);

    if (Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, waypointPosition) > length of one step)
    {
      gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveToward(gameObject.transform.position, waypointPosition);
    }
    else
    {
      gameObject.transform.position = waypointPosition;
      log("Waypoint reached");
      waypointIndex++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I used Vector3.MoveTowards because i wanted the "animation" of the object that reaches that waypoint. I'm sorry but i'm a little noob and I didn't understand your pseudocode (i don't want to delete my waypoints when i reach them). 

" Instead, you can check whether the distance to the waypoint is less than Time.deltaTime * enemy.enemy.easySpeedMovement": I think i cannot do that because waypoint is not a float (Time.deltaTime * enemy.enemy.easySpeedMovement is a float).

Comment: You're not comparing the waypoint itself against the speed, but rather the *distance* to the waypoint. I'm not super familiar with Unity, but I'm sure there's a way to ask it to give you the distance between two points. (Perhaps `Vector3.Distance(a, b)`?) *That* value will be a float, and you can compare that against the distance moved in one step.

If you don't want to delete waypoints as you reach them, then you'll want to use either an enumerator or an index variable. An index variable is probably actually more flexible, because it allows you to add waypoints. I'll update the answer.

Comment: It works like a charm! You will get the best answer! I added  the waypointIndex as index of the variable that you called "waypoints", a third argument of MoveTowards (that is the length of one step), and an "else" statement that does "waypointIndex = 0;" if every waypoint were calculated! Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Use [Vector3.sqrMagnitude](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-sqrMagnitude.html) for comparing closeness. You can define how "close" is close enough. I'm going to use a waypoint as a `Vector3` in this example. You can determine the waypoint `Vector3` however you like.

```
// define this globally
public float closeEnough = 5f;

// Within your compare method
if((gameObject.transform.position - waypoint).sqrMagnitude < closeEnough)
{
   Debug.Log("waypoint reached");
}
```

Note: The result of the `Vector3 - Vector3`, is another `Vector3`.